# Is there a way to call a "new" object constructor inside of an array all housed in an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, constructor

Putting an object with both an object constructor and an array calling a "new" of the object constructor makes it so that there is an error message that states that the object constructor name is not defined.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
var game = {
  //constructor function for every block type
  blockType: function(name, imageX, imageY, width, height, xEffect, yEffect, passable) {
    //name is just for reference
    this.name = name;
    this.imageX = imageX;
    this.imageY = imageY;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.xEffect = xEffect;
    this.yEffect = yEffect;
    //if collision would be on or off
    this.passable = passable;
  },

  blockTypes: [new blockType("basicBlack", 0, 0, 50, 50, 0, 0, false)],

};
```

The error message says

> blockType is not defined

When I put, `new game.blockType` instead, there was the error message,

> game is undefined

Am I declaring or calling things wrong, or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: `[new blockType(...` is called on the spot while the object is still being defined, so it's not defined yet. You can defined that after the object got defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new blockType` references a variable with that name, but there is no such variable. Note that `game.blockType` is a property, not a variable.

`new game.blockType` is evaluated before `game` is assigned a value, so that cannot work either.

There are many solutions. For instance, first define `game` without the second property, and then add it:

```js
var game = {
  //constructor function for every block type
  blockType: function(name, imageX, imageY, width, height, xEffect, yEffect, passable) {
    //name is just for reference
    this.name = name;
    this.imageX = imageX;
    this.imageY = imageY;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.xEffect = xEffect;
    this.yEffect = yEffect;
    //if collision would be on or off
    this.passable = passable;
  },

};

game.blockTypes = [new game.blockType("basicBlack", 0, 0, 50, 50, 0, 0, false)];

console.log(game);
```

Another solution is to first create `blockType` as a (local) variable:

```js
var game = (() => {
  //constructor function for every block type
  const blockType = function(name, imageX, imageY, width, height, xEffect, yEffect, passable) {
    //name is just for reference
    this.name = name;
    this.imageX = imageX;
    this.imageY = imageY;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.xEffect = xEffect;
    this.yEffect = yEffect;
    //if collision would be on or off
    this.passable = passable;
  };
  const blockTypes = [new blockType("basicBlack", 0, 0, 50, 50, 0, 0, false)];
  return {blockType, blockTypes};
})(); // Immediately invoked function expression

console.log(game);
```

Comment: Thank you. The first method has resolved my issue well.